# How to avoid to get your clothes to disappear in Indonesian laundry services?

Tags: tips-and-tricks, indonesia, laundry

My clothes often "disappear" in laundry services here in Indonesia.

People told me this happens often.

Anyone got tips on how to avoid this to happen?

I imagine that whoever lives here long enough figured out a good way to still use those laundry services without "losing" all their clothes one by one.

Comment: My "answer" is that I always wash my own clothes.  :-)

Comment: Which is not a valid anwser, as I wrote "in Indonesian laundry services" ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Count the number of pieces you leave at the laundry shop in front of the laundry lady and have her write it down on a piece of paper.  Then count the pieces you get back, again in front of her.